# React Plaid Link Error Loading Plaid Null

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, plaid

I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong here. I checked through some issues and it seems that error loading plaid null has been an issue in the past. I am able to successfully create the link token and display it before pass into PlaidLink. The PlaidLink button remains disabled and in console I get error loading plaid null. What am I missing? Here is a link to the Plaid documents. https://github.com/plaid/react-plaid-link

I'm using "react-plaid-link": "^3.2.0"

Here is my code.

```
import React, { useCallback, useState, FunctionComponent, useEffect } from "react";
import { usePlaidLink, PlaidLinkOptions, PlaidLinkOnSuccess } from "react-plaid-link";
// @ts-ignore
//import { PlaidLinkOnSuccess } from "react-plaid-link/src/types/index.ts";



interface Props {
  token: string;
}

const PlaidLink: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ token }) => {


  const onSuccess = useCallback<PlaidLinkOnSuccess>(
(public_token: any, metadata: any) => {
  // send public_token to server
  const setToken = async () => {
    console.log("token sending to server for exchange")
    const response = await fetch("/api/set_access_token", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
      },
      body: `public_token=${public_token}`,
    });
  };
},
[]
  );

  const config: PlaidLinkOptions = {
token,
onSuccess,
// onExit
// onEvent
  };



  const { open, ready, error } = usePlaidLink(config);

  return (
<div>
  <p>{token}</p>
  <button
    onClick={() => open()}
    disabled={!ready}
  >
    Connect a bank account
  </button>
</div>
  );
};


const PrePlaid: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string | null>(null);

  // generate a link_token
  React.useEffect(() => {
async function createLinkToken() {
  let response = await fetch("/api/create_link_token");
  const { link_token } = await response.json();
  console.log("this is the link token" + link_token);
  setToken(link_token);
}
console.log("this should happen first")
createLinkToken();
  }, []);

  // only initialize Link once our token exists
  return token === null ? (
// insert your loading animation here
<div className="loader"></div>
  ) : (
  <PlaidLink token={token} />
  );
    }

export default PrePlaid;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was missing script tag in index.html

Comment: hi @aeipownu, Plaid engineer here. What script tag did you add? As far as I know react-plaid-link is supposed to inject the script tag into your document <head> tag automatically, so I am a bit stumped why this was the fix for you. Anyways, glad you got it figured out! Your code above in the original question looks fine to me.

Comment: It was the one for the javascript docs.

<script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>
This was also me. https://github.com/plaid/react-plaid-link/issues/203 Might give you a bit more info. But yeah weird bug and was quite the pain to figure out. I thought it odd that the importance of the script tag was left out on the React docs, but it makes sense now that it's supposed to be automatically added. I had issues with the import lines as well which are supposed to be the easiest parts! specifically {PlaidLinkOnSuccess}